# asp.net mvc : Images,Css files & javascript files are not being cached

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc

I din't want my pages to be cached for security and for consistency.
When I hit back button on browser, it should always go to server to get the html.

I achieved it by creating the following actionfilter.

```
public class NoCache : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

I applied to filter to to everything as a global filter

```
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        // Makes sure that cached pages are not served to any browser including chrome
        filters.Add(new NoCache());
    }
```

The problem was solved. But now all Images, css and javascript files are also not being cached.
**How I tell it to cache them?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try enabling cache in your `web.config`:

The `<clientCache>` element of the `<staticContent>` element specifies cache-related HTTP headers that Internet Information Services (IIS)  sends to Web clients, which control how Web clients and proxy servers will cache the content that IIS returns.

For example, the `httpExpires` attribute specifies a date and time that the content should expire, and IIS will add an HTTP "`Expires`" header to the response. The value for the `httpExpires` attribute must be a fully-formatted date and time that follows the specification in `RFC 1123`. For example:

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
         <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseExpires"
            httpExpires="Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT" />
      </staticContent>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

You can refer [this link](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/clientcache) for more info.